# React Suspense Concurrent Mode Not Working

Tags: reactjs, jsx, react-suspense

I am trying to use react suspense but I am facing some issue regarding rendering after making changes in react index.js file and I already installed react suspense "npm install react@experimental react-dom@experimental"

**My index.js file**

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

[Index.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpqjM.png)

**Error**

```
TypeError: react_dom__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1___default.a.createRoot is not a function
```

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AHudQ.png)

Comment: Did you search for the error message? It seems like it is this issue here: https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/18866

Comment: I tried to search but not getting any thing which might help

1- npx create-react-app my-app --template typescript
 
2- cd my-app && yarn upgrade react@experimental react-dom@experimental
refrence types in react-app-env.d.ts

3- /// <reference types="react-scripts" /> /// <reference types="react/experimental" /> /// <reference types="react-dom/experimental" />

What does this 3rd point means?

Comment: None of that should be relevant. Look at the answer provided in the issue linked above. React renamed `createRoot` to `unstable_createRoot` back in May. So try using `ReactDOM.unable_createRoot` instead of `ReactDOM.createRoot`

Comment: Wow it's working now 
I am reading official docs so in there official docs they mentioned the old syntax
Btw thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

To anyone updating an old React App, the React support doc on React 18 says to write ONLY:

```sh
npm install react react-dom
```

for the React 18 update.
I had two React 16 apps I wanted to update.

To do so, I first updated to React 17:

```sh
npm install react@17.0.0 react-dom@17.0.0
```

ONLY AFTER this version is installed properly, you are able to install to 18, specifying the version in the installation command:

```sh
npm install react@18.0.0 react-dom@18.0.0
```

After that,

```js
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

works just fine.
Follow the version update on your 'package,json' file.

Answer (score 1):

In order to works is required to use ReactDOM.unstable_createRoot

```html
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import App from "./App";

ReactDOM.unstable_createRoot(document.getElementById("root")).render(<App />);
```

Answer (score 0):

change  -> `import ReactDOM from "react-dom";`

to -> `import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";`

Answer (score 0):

The function `createRoot` is from `react-dom/client`. You can try the named import like this:

```
import React from "react";
import { createRoot } from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";

const root = createRoot(document.getElementById("root"));
root.render(<App />);
```